# Uninstall package linked in cocoa pods for react native 0.63

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I have an npm package I installed which I linked to cocoa pods via

```
npx pod install
```

I am looking to uninstall this pod as I have already uninstalled the npm package and am having trouble finding an article I am confident in trying since I am new to react-native and want to avoid crashing my app by making a mistake. Is there any easy process to complete this task?

**EXTRA**

xCode 12.4

React Native 0.63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `Pod install`, it checks `package.json` and install pods for only those packages thats requires pod installation. RN v0.63 handles linking and unlinking itself, you don't need to worry about that, it has nothing to do with pod install command. Just do `npm uninstall <package-name>` and then re-run `pod install` to update pods as per package.json.